# Convert Data to URL for AVPlayer

Tags: swift3, realm, realm-mobile-platform

I am using realm to store my data offline. I am storing video file as raw Data in the realm. I am using AVPlayer to play my video and it only takes URL as parameters. I tried different things to convert my raw data to URL, but it doesn't seem to be working. I checked the size of data and it stores and retrieves data properly, the only problem I have is to convert that data to the correct format(URL) so that AVPlayer can play that video.

Comment: There is no way to "convert" the data to URL. The URL is a value that identifies the location of a resource. There is a previous history of "Store Images or to Realm," so maybe you're covered on that matter. So, right now, you're going to need to provide the URL containing the Path on where your video is stored. Meaning that if you store your video on the device it should be stored on the filesystem directly as a file.

Comment: @Orlando I am storing raw data into the realm, do you think I should find the path to that data?

Comment: Well, the thing is there is no path to the data stored on Realm. Realm does all the job on the filesystem so you have no access to the data. You should make two changes: 1) Store the data (in this case the video files) to the disk directly and 2) Store the Path of the saved media files on Realm. After that you just initialize the `AVPlayer` object with the disk path for the videos.

Answer (score 1):

You need to write raw data to temporary file and then provide its URL to `AVPlayer`.

```
let tmpFileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent("video").appendingPathExtension("mp4")
let wasFileWritten = (try? data.write(to: tmpFileURL, options: [.atomic])) != nil

if !wasFileWritten{
    print("File was NOT Written")
}
...
//play url with your AVPlayer
```

Comment: I think that's a good solution. The only concern I have is storage. Wouldn't I be storing same data at two locations on my device?

Comment: @VandanPatel you will store your temporary file in /temporary folder. iOS will clean it when it will need more space. Also, you will use only one temporary file, so it's not an issue.

Comment: @VandanPatel You can also remove temporary file after you don't need it.

Comment: I will definitely try it and accept your answer when I am done. I was going nowhere with this, so thanks a lot, friend!

Comment: @VandanPatel The second way is to store videos in /Documents folder, and to have paths to them in your Realm database. Then you can get URL from file path... It's much easier.

Comment: you are right. I should try that. That leads me to think that there is no easy way to store audio and video data directly to the realm. You can correct me if i am wrong.

Comment: @VandanPatel. Also, keep in mind that Data and String properties in Realm cannot hold data exceeding 16MB in size.

Comment: Thanks for the information. It would really help me. 16 MB is still a pretty good size though. right?

Comment: @VandanPatel I’m note sure that 16Mb for videos is good enough.